# Trying to authenticate with signInWithCustomToken with strange errors

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to authenticate admin to enable write access to Firebase DB.

I wanted to create a custom UID, which would only be passed to admin account which would then verify itself as `write` access account with the DB rules set to:

```
"rules": {
  ".read": true,
  ".write": "auth.uid === 'some_uid'"
}
```

I tried the recomended way of first intializing app with:

```
this.config = {
  apiKey: api_key
  authDomain: auth_domain
  databaseURL: db_url
  messagingSenderId: ...
  projectId: ...
  storageBucket: ...
  token: ...
}

firebase.initializeApp(this.config)
```

And then passing the token returned previously from server to the `createCustomToken()` function to create an UID and log-in the user with it.

```
firebase
  .auth()
  .createCustomToken(this.config.token)
  .then((token) => {
    firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token)
      .then(() => {
        ...some logic
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error)
      })
  })
```

I get `TypeError: firebase.auth(...).createCustomToken is not a function`

I know I am initializing the app correctly, because if I delete the steps with `tokens`, ie: `createCustomToken` and `signInWithCustomToken` and just run my logic, which fetches data from `firebaseDB`, then everything works.

So the question is, how am I initializing it wrong, if the `firebase.auth(...)` doesnt have function `createCustomToken` on it, but the docs say it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing the Admin and client SDKs. `createCustomToken` is in the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens). The `signInWithCustomToken` is in the [client SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth).

You would typically mint the custom token with the admin SDK on the server and then send it back to the client to complete sign in using client SDK.